# EXT JS 4.0.7 window fit breaks after close

Tags: extjs, layout, resize, window

So I have the following window.

```
var myWindow = Ext.create("Ext.window.Window", {
                         width          :  600,
                         title          :  "Window",
                         draggable      :  true,
                         border         :  false,
             resizable  :  true,
             autoScroll :  true,
                         layout         :  "fit",
                         items          : form, 
                         modal          : true
};
```

And this is my form:

```
var form= Ext.create("Ext.form.Panel", {
    border          : false,
    frame           : true, 
    items           : items,
    fbar            : buttons
});
```

There's a lot of things that are hidden and show if some things are clicked. This causes the size of the form to change regularly. At first this is no problem, the window always resizes itself to fit the form. But if I close or resize the window, the window no longer fits the form. It is as layout : 'fit' doesn't work anymore after close/resize.

Any ideas?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It should not adjust size after user re-sized it - I think it's expected behavior. What do you mean 'after close'? Do you hide or destroy window?

Comment: When I click the x button or a,special button that calls window.hide(). There's field sets in this window. Some are collapse. Before closing the window or resizing it, the field sets expand and the window is resized (it gets bigger). After closing the window or resizing it, when the field sets expand, it just overflows. Half of it is hidden because the window doesn't resize, doesn't get bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Once you resize a panel, width and height are FIXED. Every time the layout has to be recalculated it verifies if width and height are fixed or not in order to determinate if width and height should be recalculted or not.

This makes sense because you cannot have both (auto fit and custom size) at the same time. What you can do is set width and height to undefined and call doLayout() after you show new content.